# jQuery Encoding Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding

I'm using the next code jQuery code  -

```
         success: function(result){     
          $('#taglineResults').text(result) ;
           alert('אבג');
         }
```

as you can see the content in the alert is in hebrew , but the alert I get is three rectangles.
I've tried using `unescape` and `decodeUri` but it didn't help, how could I solve this problem?

Thanks in advnace

Comment: Perhaps your browser doesn't have the hebrew glyphs so it's not displaying them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**this 100% works.** Change encoding of your source code file to utf-8. 
You can use notepad++ for this. Then rewrite your text in hebrew again and save.

You will see hebrew in alert.

Answer (score 1):

If it's showing as blocks, the font your system/browser uses for alerts doesn't support those characters. I wouldn't use an alert in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. If he can see hebrew here: http://jsfiddle.net/h5aFK/1/ - then its possible to make these alerts work.

Comment: Perhaps he can. I was assuming his document was using the right character encoding, though... (otherwise he'd have probably run into hebrew character issues earlier... that is unless this is the first hebrew he's used). Then, I thought he *must* be using windows, and probably IE. IE uses system alerts, thus likely using some default system font. Those system fonts often don't support very many characters. total long shot... in hindsight, the wrong character encoding seems a bit more likely. But who knows. @Itamar : please try Dmitriy's jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can us `\u` notation

```
alert("\u05D3\u05D4\u05D5");​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4S3m/)

[character chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0590.pdf)